Rails Excel Export has wrong formatting of numbers
My Rails app offers the ability to export payments and invoices in Excel format using the caxlsx and calsx_rails gem.
The export itself works fine. The invoice values though are properly formatted in LibreOffice but formatted wrongly in MS Excel as "text" instead of being "numbers" which you then cannot add up and suddenly have a "EUR" symbol in the end. So it looks like a currency but again adding up is not possible.
I didnt program this myself but will share the code from invoices_payments.xlsx:
adapter = Download::Xlsx
worksheet_names = adapter.worksheet_names()
in_invoices_header = adapter.in_invoices_header()
out_invoices_header = adapter.out_invoices_header()
in_payments_header = adapter.in_payments_header()
out_payments_header = adapter.out_payments_header()

# Init a workbook
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
xlsx_package.use_shared_strings = true

# Define some common styles
styles = wb.styles
horizontal_right = styles.add_style(alignment: {horizontal: :right})
border_cell = styles.add_style(border: Axlsx::STYLE_THIN_BORDER)
invoice_date_field_style = styles.add_style(border: Axlsx::STYLE_THIN_BORDER, alignment: {horizontal: :right}, format_code: 'yyyy-mm-dd')
invoice_text_field_style = styles.add_style(border: Axlsx::STYLE_THIN_BORDER, alignment: {horizontal: :right})

# Invoice data cells format
invoice_format = {
  date: invoice_date_field_style,
  text: invoice_text_field_style,
  value: styles.add_style(:format_code => "")
}
invoice_cells_formats = Array.new(in_invoices_header.size, invoice_format[:text])
invoice_cells_formats[0] = invoice_format[:date]
invoice_cells_formats[11] = invoice_format[:value]
invoice_cells_formats[13] = invoice_format[:value]
invoice_cells_formats[14] = invoice_format[:value]

# Create Invoices worksheet in this workbook
wb.add_worksheet(name: worksheet_names[:in_invoices]) do |worksheet|
  # Add in_invoice headers
  invoice_header_row = worksheet.add_row(in_invoices_header, b: true)

  # Add in_invoice data
  if @in_invoices.present?
    @in_invoices.each do |in_invoice|
      row = worksheet.add_row([
        in_invoice.issuing_date.to_date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"),
        in_invoice.department&.name,
        in_invoice.number,
        in_invoice.other_company_name_str,
        in_invoice.other_company_street_and_no_str,
        in_invoice.other_company_postal_code_str,
        in_invoice.other_company_city_str,
        in_invoice.other_company_tax_number,
        in_invoice.other_company_fitaf_id,
        in_invoice.service_description,
        in_invoice.internal_note,
        in_invoice.net,
        "#{in_invoice.vat_rate} %",
        in_invoice.vat,
        in_invoice.gross,
        in_invoice.currency,
        (in_invoice.privately_paid? ? "Privat ausgelegt" : 'Nicht privat ausgelegt'),
        "Eingangsrechnung",
        (in_invoice.to_be_paid.present? ? in_invoice.to_be_paid.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") : ""),
        in_invoice.paid_via,
        (in_invoice.physical_copy.attached? ? "Ja" : "Nein"),
        (in_invoice.is_a_hospitality_receipt ? "Bewirtungsbeleg" : "Kein Bewirtungsbeleg"),
        in_invoice.place_of_hospitality,
        in_invoice.date_of_hospitality&.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"),
        in_invoice.reason_for_hospitality,
        (in_invoice.tip_of_hospitality if in_invoice.tip_of_hospitality.present?),
        in_invoice.participants_of_hospitality,
        in_invoice.name_of_hospitality_250_eur,
        in_invoice.address_of_hospitality_250_eur,
        in_invoice.tax_number_of_hospitality_250_eur,
        in_invoice.eur_object.try(:name),
        (in_invoice.durable ? "Ja" : "Nein"),
        (in_invoice.durable ? in_invoice.cycle : ""),
        (in_invoice.durable ? in_invoice.durable_until.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") : ""),
        (in_invoice.archived? ? "Ja" : "Nein"),
        (in_invoice.proposal? ? "Ja" : "Nein"),
        in_invoice.creditor_id,
        in_invoice.debitable_bank_account_owner,
        in_invoice.debitable_bank_account_number,
        in_invoice.debitable_bank_name,
        in_invoice.debitable_bank_number,
            ], style: invoice_cells_formats)
    end
  end
end
wb.add_worksheet(name: worksheet_names[:out_invoices]) do |worksheet|
    # Add in_invoice headers
    invoice_header_row = worksheet.add_row(out_invoices_header, b: true)

  # Add out_invoice data
  if @out_invoices.present?
    @out_invoices.each do |out_invoice|
      row = worksheet.add_row([
              german_date(out_invoice.issuing_date),
              out_invoice.department&.name,
              out_invoice.number,
              out_invoice.other_company_name_str,
              out_invoice.other_company_street_and_no_str,
              out_invoice.other_company_postal_code_str,
              out_invoice.other_company_city_str,
              out_invoice.other_company_tax_number,
              out_invoice.other_company_fitaf_id,
              out_invoice.service_description,
              out_invoice.internal_note,
              out_invoice.net,
              "#{out_invoice.vat_rate} %",
              out_invoice.vat,
              out_invoice.gross,
              out_invoice.currency,
              german_date(out_invoice.to_be_paid),
              out_invoice.paid_via,
              out_invoice.physical_copy.attached? ? "Ja" : "Nein",
              "Ausgangsrechnung",
              out_invoice.try(:other_company_fitaf_id),
              out_invoice.eur_object.try(:name),
              out_invoice.durable ? "Dauerrechnung" : "Keine Dauerrechnung",
              out_invoice.durable ? out_invoice.cycle : "",
              out_invoice.durable ? out_invoice.durable_until.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") : "",
              out_invoice.archived ? "Rechnung archiviert" : "Rechnung nicht archiviert",
              out_invoice.creditor_id,
              out_invoice.debitable_bank_account_owner,
              out_invoice.debitable_bank_account_number,
              out_invoice.debitable_bank_name,
              out_invoice.debitable_bank_number
            ], style: invoice_cells_formats)
      if out_invoice.physical_copy.attached?
        worksheet.add_hyperlink :location => link_to_invoice_physical_contract(out_invoice), :ref => row.cells.last
      end
    end
  end

  # Calculate row index to except style for rows with in_invoice/ out_invoice data
  last_invoice_data_row_index = invoice_header_row.row_index + @out_invoices.size + @out_invoices.size

  # Add style for all rows
  worksheet.rows.each_with_index do |row, index|
    ## Don't add common styles for rows between specific index ranges
    next if index > invoice_header_row.row_index && index <= last_invoice_data_row_index
    ## Add common styles for other rows
    row.style = horizontal_right
    row.style = border_cell
  end
end

# Create Payments worksheet in this workbook
wb.add_worksheet(name: worksheet_names[:in_payments]) do |worksheet|
  # Add in_payment headers
  worksheet.add_row(in_payments_header, b: true)

  # Add in_payment data
  if @in_payments.present?
    @in_payments.each do |in_payment|
      ## Define specific styles for each data row
      in_payment_date_format = styles.add_style(border: Axlsx::STYLE_THIN_BORDER, alignment: {horizontal: :right}, format_code: 'dd.mm.yyyy')
      in_payment_text_format = styles.add_style(border: Axlsx::STYLE_THIN_BORDER, alignment: {horizontal: :right})
      in_payment_value_format = styles.add_style(:format_code => "")
      in_payment_cells_formats = Array.new(in_payments_header.size, in_payment_text_format)
      in_payment_cells_formats[0] = in_payment_date_format
      in_payment_cells_formats[2] = in_payment_value_format

      # Row data
      worksheet.add_row([
        in_payment.transaction_date,
        in_payment.department&.name,
        in_payment.value,
        in_payment.other_company_str,
        in_payment.reason,
        in_payment.mean_of_payment.andand.account_name
      ], style: in_payment_cells_formats)
    end
  end
end

wb.add_worksheet(name: worksheet_names[:out_payments]) do |worksheet|
  # Add in_payment headers
  out_payment_header_row = worksheet.add_row(out_payments_header, b: true)
  # Add out_payment data
  if @out_payments.present?
    @out_payments.each do |out_payment|
      ## Define specific styles for each data row
      out_payment_date_format = styles.add_style(border: Axlsx::STYLE_THIN_BORDER, alignment: {horizontal: :right}, format_code: 'dd.mm.yyyy')
      out_payment_text_format = styles.add_style(border: Axlsx::STYLE_THIN_BORDER, alignment: {horizontal: :right})
      out_payment_value_format = styles.add_style(:format_code => "")
      out_payment_cells_formats = Array.new(out_payments_header.size, out_payment_text_format)
      out_payment_cells_formats[0] = out_payment_date_format
      out_payment_cells_formats[2] = out_payment_value_format

      ## Row data
      worksheet.add_row([
        out_payment.transaction_date,
        out_payment.department&.name,
        -out_payment.value,
        out_payment.other_company_str,
        out_payment.reason,
        out_payment.mean_of_payment.andand.account_name
      ], style: out_payment_cells_formats)
    end
  end

  # Calculate row index to except style for rows with in_payment/ out_payment data
  last_payment_data_index = out_payment_header_row.row_index + @in_payments.size + @out_payments.size

  # Add style for all rows
  worksheet.rows.each_with_index do |row, index|
    ## Don't add common styles for rows between specific index ranges
    next if index > out_payment_header_row.row_index && index <= last_payment_data_index
    ## Add common styles for other rows
    row.style = horizontal_right
    row.style = border_cell
  end
end


With Excel this is never straightforward, but for starters, try adding a bit of formatting to explicitly treat the values as numbers with currency formatting. As an example
value: styles.add_style(:format_code => '€#,##0.00')

The hint from the comment unfortunately didn't work." €" was still displayed in Excel. In general the field in Excel was trated of type "text" .Learned by further reasearch that I can styles with different number formats.
In my case: styles.add_style(num_fmt: 2)
Now the values are displayed as such and adding up works.
